# App Crashes on the device iphone 4s 5.0.1 not in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, sdk, ios-simulator

Tested on the iphone 4s device (ver) 5.0.1.

Crashes: When you click on the tab to inter into the index page from main page

1)main.m

```
  //
  //  main.m
  //  salah1
  //  Created by syed ali on 30/11/2011.
  //  Copyright (c) 2011 j h birmingham. All rights reserved.
  //

  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

   #import "AppDelegate.h"

  int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
     @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
   }
   }
```

2) LOCAL:

```
  argc  int 1
  argv  char ** 0x2fdffbb4
 *argv  char *  0x2fdffc68
```

3) ALL OUTPUT:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Fri Sep 16 06:56:50 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=i386-apple-darwin --target=arm-apple-darwin".tty /dev/ttys000
target remote-mobile /tmp/.XcodeGDBRemote-19819-51
Switching to remote-macosx protocol
mem 0x1000 0x3fffffff cache
mem 0x40000000 0xffffffff none
mem 0x00000000 0x0fff none
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/yakub121/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader (file not found).
warning: No copy of AccessibilitySettingsLoader.bundle/AccessibilitySettingsLoader found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
[Switching to process 8963 thread 0x2303]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/yakub121/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/UIKit.axbundle/UIKit (file not found).
warning: No copy of UIKit.axbundle/UIKit found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
[Switching to process 9219 thread 0x2403]
[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/yakub121/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/TelephonyUIFramework.axbundle/TelephonyUIFramework (file not found).
warning: No copy of TelephonyUIFramework.axbundle/TelephonyUIFramework found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/yakub121/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/TextInput.axbundle/TextInput (file not found).
warning: No copy of TextInput.axbundle/TextInput found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/yakub121/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/MediaPlayerFramework.axbundle/MediaPlayerFramework (file not found).
warning: No copy of MediaPlayerFramework.axbundle/MediaPlayerFramework found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/yakub121/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/iTunesStoreFramework.axbundle/iTunesStoreFramework (file not found).
warning: No copy of iTunesStoreFramework.axbundle/iTunesStoreFramework found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/yakub121/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/AXExtraExtras.axbundle/AXExtraExtras (file not found).
warning: No copy of AXExtraExtras.axbundle/AXExtraExtras found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/yakub121/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/QuickSpeak.bundle/QuickSpeak (file not found).
warning: No copy of QuickSpeak.bundle/QuickSpeak found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
[Switching to process 9731 thread 0x2603]
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Users/yakub121/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/5.0.1 (9A405)/Symbols/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/PreferencesFramework.axbundle/PreferencesFramework (file not found).
warning: No copy of PreferencesFramework.axbundle/PreferencesFramework found locally, reading from memory on remote device.  This may slow down the debug session.
2011-12-08 11:14:48.095 salah1[3198:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/F9548CB5-9248-4C10-AEE7-B843DE8E1D36/salah1.app> (loaded)' with name 'Custom_Cell''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x3802e8bf 0x31b141e5 0x3802e7b9 0x3802e7db 0x3565a747 0x3565bbb9 0x2a03 0x354469cb 0x35445aa9 0x35445233 0x353e9d4b 0x37f8d22b 0x33784381 0x33783f99 0x3378811b 0x33787e57 0x3377fd85 0x38002b4b 0x38000d87 0x380010e1 0x37f844dd 0x37f843a5 0x37b02fcd 0x35414743 0x21cd 0x2164)
terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 7171 thread 0x1c03]
(gdb)
```

Comment: Does it work in the simulator, but not the device? Or does it not work at all?

Answer (score 7):

Your problem is that one of the nibs names is not correctly named:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle (loaded)' with name 'Custom_Cell'**

The simulator is not case sensitive but the iPhone is. So `Custom_Cell` != `custom_cell`

Comment: Upvote for mentioning the case-sensitive differences between the simulator and the device.

Answer (score 2):

The error is right in the GDB stack that you provided:

```
'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/F9548CB5-9248-4C10-AEE7-B843DE8E1D36/salah1.app> (loaded)' with name 'Custom_Cell''
```

Do you have a NIB with the name **Custom_Cell**? Can you show us the code that is executing when the crash occurs? Can you show us how your **Custom_Cell** is defined in Interface Builder?